# Jquery parallax video top

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

I need a script to make parallax with one video

[website example with video on top, where need parallax](http://fabioerafael.com.br/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin such as http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/ to make your video element have a parallax effect.

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/ntzosfg2/

```
<video data-stellar-ratio="0.5">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: this don't work for me, i don't know why... but don't work 
the video stay at the top and don't make the parallax effect